# Froala add custom pre code button

Tags: button, tags, customization, wysiwyg, froala

I'm trying to create a code button with the [Froala](http://editor.froala.com/) editor which can basicly do the same thing as here on SO by pressing `CNTRL+K`. Now I think I have two choices.

The first one is to edit the froala-editor.js file, because Froala already has a 'code' button which only adds the `<pre>` tags. If I could somehow get it to also add the `<code>` tag, problem solved. Unfortunately I didn't get this to work.

The second option is to create a custom button, so far I have this piece of code:

```
$('textarea[name="description"]').editable({
    //Settings here
    customButtons: {
        insertCode: {
            title: 'Insert code',
            icon: {
                type: 'font',
                value: 'fa fa-code'
            },
            callback: function() {
                this.saveSelection();

                if (!this.selectionInEditor()) {
                    this.$element.focus(); // Focus on editor if it's not.
                }

                var html = '<pre><code>' + this.text() + ' </code></pre>';

                this.restoreSelection();
                this.insertHTML(html);
                this.saveUndoStep();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

It works somehow, but it's buggy and produces strange html like so:

```
<p><code></code>
  <pre><code>asdasdasdasd
</code></pre>
</p>
```

Any help with getting this done for either option one or two would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you upgrade to version 1.2.3 that is available on Github your code should work https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor. It's not necessary to save/restore selection.

---

LATER EDIT:
Here is a jsFiddle for it http://jsfiddle.net/9pmmg1jk/.

```js
customButtons: {
  insertCode: {
    title: 'Insert code',
      icon: {
        type: 'font',
          value: 'fa fa-code'
      },
        callback: function() {
          if (!this.selectionInEditor()) {
            this.$element.focus(); // Focus on editor if it's not.
          }

          var html = '<code>' + (this.text() || '&#8203;') + '<span class="f-marker" data-type="false" data-id="0" data-fr-verified="true"></span><span class="f-marker" data-type="true" data-id="0" data-fr-verified="true"></span></code>';

          this.insertHTML(html);
          this.restoreSelectionByMarkers();
          this.saveUndoStep();
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I manually replaced the JS files with the new ones from GitHub. I also deleted the lines `this.saveSelection()` and `this.restoreSelection()`. When I click the custom button I get the HTML: `<p class=""><code></code>
  <pre><code>code </code></pre>
</p>`. So it's not working. I would like it to work the same as the default 'code' button if that's possible, which currently also strips the `<p>` tags but only adds the `<pre>` tag and not the `<code>` tag. I hope I make any sence to you, thanks in advance!

Comment: I edited the comment and added a jsFiddle from where you can start.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. I could also easily add the `<pre>` tag. I love Froala editor, it has everything I need. Could you explain what the marker spans do?

Comment: Yes, they place the cursor inside the `<code>` tag together with `this.restoreSelectionByMarkers();`.

Comment: The attached fiddler could be a be more concise