# Froala Add Inline Style Custom Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, froala

I'm a UX Designer, with some experience in frontend dev, working in a online editor proof of concept to be tested in a usability study. One of our first finding has been that the users would like to have a button that adds directly the corporate font family and size for body text that is Arial 11px. I know that this can be achieved easily with the inlineStyle.js plugin with a dropdown but I'd like to have the same behaviour like the Bold or Italic button. I've tried to look into the plugin's code but I can't make it work for my case I've also tried the code in this example [Froala add custom pre code button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392277/froala-add-custom-pre-code-button) but it's too old to work with the latest version of froala.

Thanks.

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this also. Anyone from Froala paying attention...?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the way forward could be to actually employ the inlineStyle plugin, then reach into the Froala editor instance and hide the plugin button on the toolbar, whilst adding your own custom button to 'click' the hidden style option in the plugins dropdown.

I don't have the inlineStyles plugin enabled right now but I do have the paragraphStyles plugin which I believe follows the same approach. This picture is a grab from Chromes inspector showing the elements that build the Froala paragraphStyle options dropdown (similar to inlinStyles). The yellow highlight is within the class of an  element that 'is' the activating button for my style. The highlighted text is my class name - the class I want applied when that option is clicked. That gives me the chance to target a click trigger via, say, jQuery, so

```
$('.dzTtlRed').trigger('click'....)
```

So you would add a custom button to the Froala editor toolbar and set it to trigger the click on your style options in the dropdown.

[image]

Regarding hiding the plugin button, this is what I have successfully used to hide the paragraphStyle plugin dropdown button on the Froala toolbar. I expect you could do the same for inlineStyles. Note you need to fire this after the Froala editor finishes building - I have noticed some async behaviour in this which means things don't happen immediately or in any externally predictable sequence, so you may want to use the Froala intialized callback event.

```
var inputBox = $('#' + eleId); // eleId is the Froala nominate textarea html id attr.
inputBox.closest("div").find("button[data-cmd='paragraphStyle']").hide();
```